# Flutter Desktop Ignore Mouse Events

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop, flutter-design

I'm looking to implement a Flutter Desktop application that allows a transparent window which forwards all touch events, like Zoom screen share.

My understanding is the behaviour can be achieved in electron using:

```
mainWindow.setIgnoreMouseEvents(true);

  const el = document.getElementById('clickThroughElement');
  el.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    mainWindow.setIgnoreMouseEvents(true, { forward: true });
  });
  el.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    mainWindow.setIgnoreMouseEvents(false);
  });
};
```

With Flutter Desktop still being in Alpha,

1. Is this feature possible?
2. Is there another approach?
3. Is it on the feature radar?

Comment: You've tried https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IgnorePointer-class.html already?

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately doesn't pass through the window

Comment: @MousyBusiness hey how do you solve this?

Comment: I didn't get a good solution, I was intercepting the click events then forwarding them but it had all kinds of messy results.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the native C++ code specifically in

```
windows\runner\win32_window.cpp
```

and comment's the SetWindowLongPtr() function
and add the following code

```
int extendedStyleSettings = GetWindowLong(window,GWL_EXSTYLE);
SetWindowLong(window,GWL_EXSTYLE, extendedStyleSettings | WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(window, 0, 255, LWA_ALPHA);
```

The problem with this solution is I don't know how to get the mouse event back because this solution edit's the win32api window which initiating in the begging of the running app and hosting the flutter view

Comment: You can do it using the setIgnoreMouseEvents method of https://github.com/leanflutter/window_manager

Comment: @lijy91  hey how to set IgnoreMouseEvents back to false?, because all the widget cannot click